# HKWorkoutSessionDelegate Not called

Tags: swift, apple-watch, healthkit

I am trying to start a workout session using `HKWorkoutSession`. It is not starting the session.

```
    let workoutConfiguration = HKWorkoutConfiguration()
    workoutConfiguration.activityType = .running
    workoutConfiguration.locationType = .outdoor

    do {
        session = try HKWorkoutSession(healthStore: healthStore!, configuration: workoutConfiguration)
        session?.delegate = self
        session?.startActivity(with: Date())
        print((session?.state)!.rawValue)
    } catch let error {
        print(error)
    }
```

The `HKWorkoutSessionDelegate` method

`func workoutSession(_ workoutSession: HKWorkoutSession, didChangeTo toState: HKWorkoutSessionState, from fromState: HKWorkoutSessionState, date: Date)`

Never gets called.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this a few times (not enough to recreate or anything).

I think restarting Xcode and the Simulator helps.

Comment: I think actually this worked in watchOS 5 and stopped working in watchOS 6

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying this on simulator? If you are, I'd try on device. If on device, this could be because you haven't accepted HealthKit permissions? Check in `Privacy->Health` to see if your app has permissions for `HealthKit`.

Comment: I am using it on a simulator. It has all the permissions and it actually worked on the simulator before and suddenly stopped. idk y.

Comment: Did someone know the issue here? I am actually facing the same issue here that sometimes even after the start activity of session, the session remains in the not started state and the delegates are never called.